# Bootstrap Form Wizard preventing progresion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have set up a form wizard to have a customer proceed through each step successfully before advancing to the next step. I am having trouble figuring out how to have it prevent the user from going to the next page WHEN there the success key in my json is set to false. I believe the project is using the bootstrap wizard plugin. Link to docs is here.  You can see below where I am trying to prevent the next step from being progressed to but its still advancing regardless.

https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard

```
<script>
$("#pageOneSubmission").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ...,
        data:
            {
                ...
            },
        dataType: JSON,
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.success) {
                console.log("Errors");
                $('#orderForm').bootstrapWizard('disable', $('#step2').val());
            } else {
                console.log("No Errors");
                $("#user-created-confirmation").html(data);

                swal({
                    title: "Success!!",
                    text: "Your order & patient profile are saved!",
                    timer: 2500,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    type: "success"
                });



            }
        },
        error: function(jqXhr) {
            if (jqXhr.status === 422) {
                var err = JSON.parse(jqXhr.responseText);
                // this wouldn't work cause your redirecting the page, the loop
                // wouldn't loop...
                // window.location = $('#orderForm').attr('action');
                $.each(err, function(key, value) {
                    $('input [name="'+ key +'"]').next().append("<p>Test</p>");
                });
            }
        }
    }, function(){
        setTimeout(function() {

        })
    });
});


<div class="wizard order-form" id="orderForm">
        <div class="wizard-inner">
            <div class="connecting-line"></div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-scale"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active step" role="tabpanel" id="step1">

                    @include('pages.order.stepone')

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">

                    @include('pages.order.steptwo')

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">

                   @include('pages.order.stepthree')

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="complete">

                    <h3>Complete</h3>
                    <p>You have successfully completed all steps.</p>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap wizard use tab index (started with 0) to identify which tab to disable or enable. In your HTML, the tab is represented by `li` item, but in your try to get the value of the `div` element.

If you insist on using the `div` element, try to put the necessary index value using data-attribute in the `div` as follow:

```
<script>
$("#pageOneSubmission").click(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ...,
    data:
        {
            ...
        },
    dataType: JSON,
    success: function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            console.log("Errors");
            $('#orderForm').bootstrapWizard('disable', $('#step2').data('tabindex'));
        } else {
            $('#orderForm').bootstrapWizard('enable', $('#step2').data('tabindex'));
            console.log("No Errors");
            $("#user-created-confirmation").html(data);

            swal({
                title: "Success!!",
                text: "Your order & patient profile are saved!",
                timer: 2500,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                type: "success"
            });



        }
    },
    error: function(jqXhr) {
        if (jqXhr.status === 422) {
            var err = JSON.parse(jqXhr.responseText);
            // this wouldn't work cause your redirecting the page, the loop
            // wouldn't loop...
            // window.location = $('#orderForm').attr('action');
            $.each(err, function(key, value) {
                $('input [name="'+ key +'"]').next().append("<p>Test</p>");
            });
        }
    }
}, function(){
    setTimeout(function() {

    })
  });
});

</script>
<div class="wizard order-form" id="orderForm">
    <div class="wizard-inner">
        <div class="connecting-line"></div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                    <span class="round-tab">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-scale"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                    <span class="round-tab">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                    <span class="round-tab">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete">
                    <span class="round-tab">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active step" role="tabpanel" id="step1" data-tabindex="0">

                @include('pages.order.stepone')

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2" data-tabindex="1">

                @include('pages.order.steptwo')

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3" data-tabindex="2">

               @include('pages.order.stepthree')

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="complete" data-tabindex="3">

                <h3>Complete</h3>
                <p>You have successfully completed all steps.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working for me at all. It still goes to the next page.